# Не отображается цвет на кнопку и не добавляются закругления на LinearLayout

Tags: android

1 Имеется background_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/backgroundButton" />
        <corners android:radius="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

И кнопка:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/go_to_course"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button" />
```

Почему-то применяется фиолетовый цвет, а не тот, который я указал (светло-серый). Все пути указаны точно правильно.

2 И заодоно хотел узнать почему не хотят применяться закругления на LinearLayout.
Имеется такой layout.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/corners_10">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/go_to_course"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_button" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/text" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

И файлик xml такой же как на кнопке, просто corners указаны на 10 dip

Помогите, пожалуйста, с двумя вопросами.
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: для LinearLayout попробуйте просто shape сделать. selector используется для ImageButton

Comment: Файлик corners_10.xml:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>

Не помогает, края все равно не обрезаются, похоже элементы внутренние просто перекрывают эти закругления